# Copy plotly layout from one plot to another in R

Tags: r, layout, plotly

I have to create a series of plots in R and am using `plotly` for this. A lot of them have the same axes and I would like to copy the `layout` portion of the plot without having to write it explicitly. Is there a way to do this?

**CODE**

*DATA*

```
dat <- data.frame(time = seq.POSIXt(from = Sys.time(), to = Sys.time() - weeks(4), 
                                    length.out = 720), 
                  output = rnorm(720, mean = 4000, sd = 300), 
                  temperature = rnorm(720, mean = 25, sd = 4))
```

Three plots:

```
plot1 <- plot_ly(dat) %>% 
  add_trace(x = ~time, y = ~output, name = 'Output', mode = 'lines+markers', 
            type = 'scatter') %>%
  layout(
    axis = list(title = 'Time'),
    yaxis = list(title = 'Power Output (kW)'),
    plot_bgcolor = '#EDEDED'
  )


plot2 <- plot_ly(dat) %>% 
  add_trace(x = ~time, y = ~output, name = 'Output', mode = 'lines+markers', 
            type = 'scatter') %>%
  add_trace(x = ~time, y = ~temperature, name = 'Temperature', mode = 'lines+markers', 
            type = 'scatter') %>%
  layout(
    axis = list(title = 'Time'),
    yaxis = list(title = 'Power Output (kW)'),
    yaxis2 = list(title = 'Temperature (C)', overlaying = 'y', side = 'right'),
    plot_bgcolor = '#EDEDED'
  )

plot3 <- plot_ly(dat[output > 3500, ]) %>% 
  add_trace(x = ~time, y = ~output, name = 'Output', mode = 'lines+markers', 
            type = 'scatter') %>%
  add_trace(x = ~time, y = ~temperature, name = 'Temperature', mode = 'lines+markers', 
            type = 'scatter') %>%
  layout(
    axis = list(title = 'Time'),
    yaxis = list(title = 'Power Output (kW)'),
    yaxis2 = list(title = 'Temperature (C)', overlaying = 'y', side = 'right'),
    plot_bgcolor = '#EDEDED'
  )
```

Is there a way to define a `layout` wherein I can reuse if for `plot2` and `plot3`. Something like:

```
twoAxis <- list(
  axis = list(title = 'Time'),
  yaxis = list(title = 'Power Output (kW)'),
  yaxis2 = list(title = 'Temperature (C)', overlaying = 'y', side = 'right'),
  plot_bgcolor = '#EDEDED'
)
```

For calling it in a plot:

```
plot2 <- plot_ly(dat, layout = twoAxis) %>%
     add_trace(...) %>% 
     add_trace(...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might make sense to write a wrapper around the `layout` function with some default argument values. This way, you still have the flexibility to specify different or additional input arguments if necessary:

```r
library(plotly)

## define wrapper function around `layout`
twoAxisLayout <- function(p, 
    xaxis = list(title = "Time"), 
    yaxis = list(title = "Power Output (kW)"), 
    yaxis2 = list(title = 'Temperature (C)', overlaying = 'y', side = 'right'), 
    plot_bgcolor = '#EDEDED', ...) {

    layout(p, xaxis = xaxis, yaxis = yaxis, yaxis2 = yaxis2, plot_bgcolor = plot_bgcolor, ...)

}

## use template layout function
plot2 <- plot_ly(dat) %>% 
    add_trace(x = ~time, y = ~output, name = 'Output', mode = 'lines+markers', 
        type = 'scatter') %>%
    add_trace(x = ~time, y = ~temperature, name = 'Temperature', mode = 'lines+markers', 
        type = 'scatter') %>%
    twoAxisLayout()
```

Comment: Thanks, it works and is largely what I'm going for. I think I'll try to edit it so I can select from set of different default options.

Answer (score 0):

There is likely a more concise solution, but the below should work. It is probably simpler to just define lists for each of your axis seperately. You need to define them individually and then apply them to your plots. Hope this helps!

```
    library(plotly)
dat <- data.frame(time = seq.POSIXt(from = Sys.time(), to = Sys.time() - 1000000, 
                                    length.out = 720), 
                  output = rnorm(720, mean = 4000, sd = 300), 
                  temperature = rnorm(720, mean = 25, sd = 4))



  xaxis <- list(title = 'Time')
  yaxis <- list(title = 'Power Output (kW)')
  yaxis2 <- list(title = 'Temperature (C)', overlaying = 'y', side = 'right')
  plot_bgcolor <- '#EDEDED'



plot1 <- plot_ly(dat) %>% 
  add_trace(x = ~time, y = ~output, name = 'Output', mode = 'lines+markers', 
            type = 'scatter') %>%
  layout(
    xaxis = xaxis,
    yaxis = yaxis,
    plot_bgcolor = plot_bgcolor
  )



plot2 <- plot_ly(dat) %>% 
  add_trace(x = ~time, y = ~output, name = 'Output', mode = 'lines+markers', 
            type = 'scatter') %>%
  add_trace(x = ~time, y = ~temperature, name = 'Temperature', mode = 'lines+markers', 
            type = 'scatter') %>%
  layout(
    xaxis = xaxis,
    yaxis = yaxis,
    yaxis2 = yaxis2,
    plot_bgcolor = plot_bgcolor
  )

plot3 <- plot_ly(dat[output > 3500, ]) %>% 
  add_trace(x = ~time, y = ~output, name = 'Output', mode = 'lines+markers', 
            type = 'scatter') %>%
  add_trace(x = ~time, y = ~temperature, name = 'Temperature', mode = 'lines+markers', 
            type = 'scatter') %>%
  layout(
    xaxis = xaxis,
    yaxis = yaxis,
    yaxis2 = yaxis2,
    plot_bgcolor = plot_bgcolor
  )
```

Comment: Thanks! I should've been clearer, I've used this before but it's still a lot to copy each time, especially when there's a lot of other items line annotations etc. I was really hoping to have something like a function that can spit out a list object for layout depending on some inputs and default options e.g. `AxisFunc(nYaxes = 2, ...)`

Answer (score 0):

Try `do.call`. Build a list of your layout options and then run.

```
do.call('layout', c(list(plot_object, layout_options))
```